# PySpark does not write statitics for TimeStamp and Decimal columns in Parquet format

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

I'm trying to generate Parquet files using Pyspark. I found that in the metadata of the generated Parquet files, the statistics of the TimestampType and DecimalType columns are not set (the IntegerType and DateType columns are fine).

I need the statistics (min and max) to filter the row groups when reading the parquet files using PyArrow.

I'm using pyspark 2.4.0 to generate parquet files and pyarrow 0.12.1 to read them:

```py
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
from pyarrow import parquet
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    StructField,
    StructType,
    IntegerType,
    DateType,
    TimestampType,
    DecimalType,
)

data = [
    (100, datetime.date(2019, 3, 1), datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 1), Decimal('100.0')),
    (200, datetime.date(2019, 3, 2), datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 2, 1), Decimal('200.0')),
    (300, datetime.date(2019, 3, 3), datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 1), Decimal('300.0')),
    (400, datetime.date(2019, 3, 4), datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 4, 1), Decimal('400.0')),
]
columns = [
    StructField('int_column', IntegerType()),
    StructField('date_column', DateType()),
    StructField('timestamp_column', TimestampType()),
    StructField('decimal_column', DecimalType(10, 2)),
]
schema = StructType(columns)

spark_context = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf())
sql_context = SQLContext(spark_context)
rdd = spark_context.parallelize(data)
df = sql_context.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=schema)

db_path = '/tmp/parquet_test'
df.write.parquet(db_path, compression='gzip')

dataset = parquet.ParquetDataset(db_path)
meta_data = dataset.pieces[1].get_metadata(parquet.ParquetFile)
row_group = meta_data.row_group(0)
for col_index in range(len(columns)):
    column = row_group.column(col_index)
    print(f'column name: {column.path_in_schema}, is_stats_set: {column.is_stats_set}')
```

The output of the code is:

```
column name: int_column, is_stats_set: True
column name: date_column, is_stats_set: True
column name: timestamp_column, is_stats_set: False
column name: decimal_column, is_stats_set: False
```

I don't know why the stats of the last 2 columns are not set by PySpark.

Did I miss something in the code, or it is the expected behavior of PySpark? If it is the latter, I'll need to convert the timestamp to/from integer by myself.